# Dynamic directives in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a variety of directives that I use from a third party library. These directives are, for example:

```
<v-rect :config="rectConfig"></v-rect>

<v-circle :config="circleConfig"></v-circle>

<v-triangle :config="triangleConfig"></v-triangle>
```

As you can see, the shape itself is what determines the directive I use.

But what about when that shape is dynamic, and can be changed on the fly? I'd like for the directive itself to be driven by the shape. How would I therefore achieve something akin to the below?

```
<v-{{shape}} :config="config"></v-{{shape}}> 

// ^^ Should render as <v-rect>

data() {
  return {
    shape: 'rect',
    config: {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're looking for [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

Comment: Why not use something like `<v-rect v-show="isRect">` (or `v-if`) with computed components instead—seems more idiomatic.

Comment: @DarraghEnright Because then I would need to have every possible directive for every single dynamic value (shape). That won't work.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim that works. Thanks!